# Beautifulsoup using findall() returns nothing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup I want to extract data from the following code:

```
<div class="property-tag-container">
    <span class="c-prop-tag2">距离8号线市光路站284米</span>
    <span class="c-prop-tag2">满五</span>
    <span class="c-prop-tag2">有钥匙</span>
</div>
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
for i in range (1,3):
   if i == 1:
          i = str(i)
          a = (url + page + i + '/')
          r = requests.get(url=a, headers=headers)

          html = r.content
          print(type(html),html)
   else:
          i = str(i)
          a = (url + page + i + '/')
          r = requests.get(url=a, headers=headers)
          html2 = r.content
          html = html + html2

lj=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
subway=lj.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'property-tag-
container'},limit=None)
sb=[]
for c in subway:

   subway=c.string
   sb.append(subway)
print(len(sb),sb)
```

However, nothing is in the list `sb`, so the output is as follows:

> 60 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `div` with that class and its `string` attribute is `None`.

Try this:

```
for c in subway:
   subway=c.get_text()
   sb.append(subway)
```